# Sentences-symmetric difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given the following definition:

If $A,B$ are sets, we define the set $A \triangle B =(A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$ and we call it symmetric difference of $A,B$.

I have to prove the following sentences:

1. $A \cap B= \varnothing$, then $A \triangle B=A \cup B$
2. $A \triangle A=\varnothing$
3. $A \triangle B=B \triangle A$
4. $(A \triangle B) \triangle C= A \triangle (B \triangle C)$
5. $A \cap (B \triangle C)=(A \cap B) \triangle (A \cap C)$

That's what I have tried:

1. Since $A \cap B=\varnothing$, $A \setminus B=A$ and $B \setminus A=B$.
   So, $A \triangle B=(A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)=A \cup B$

   Can we just say it like that or do we have to prove it further?

   2.Do I have to take a $x \in A \triangle A$, or isn't it necessary? :confused:

   If so, then is it like that?

   $x \in A \triangle A \leftrightarrow x \in (A \setminus A) \cup (A \setminus A)   \leftrightarrow x \in \varnothing \cup \varnothing \leftrightarrow x \in \varnothing$, that cannot be true, therefore there is no set $x$, for which $x \in A \triangle A$, so $A \triangle A=\varnothing$.

   3. $x \in A \triangle B \leftrightarrow x \in (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) \leftrightarrow x \in (A \setminus B) \lor x \in  (B \setminus A) \leftrightarrow x \in  (B \setminus A) \lor  x \in (A \setminus B) \leftrightarrow x \in B \triangle A $

Also, how can I show the last two sentences?

Comment: 1. looks fine. 2. Use the definition, you know what $A \setminus A$ is. 3. Follows since $C \cup D = D \cup C$.

Comment: 4. Is a tedious application of distributions and deMorgan rules: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_Difference_is_Associative

Comment: @copper.hat So, in order to conclude that $A \triangle A=\varnothing$, do we have to say the following?

$$A \triangle A=(A \setminus A) \cup (A \setminus A)\overset{(*)}{=} \varnothing \cup \varnothing=\varnothing$$

$$x \in A \setminus A \leftrightarrow x \in A \wedge x \notin A, \text{ that cannot be true} \Rightarrow A \setminus A=\varnothing (*)$$

Comment: I would just note that $A \setminus A = \emptyset$ and $\emptyset \cup \emptyset = \emptyset$.

Comment: And we can prove that $A \setminus A=\varnothing$, as I did at the above comment?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @copper.hat Nice!!! And is the proof I wrote for the third sentence right?

Comment: Yup. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @copper.hat Great!!! Could you also explain me how I could prove the sentences $4$ and $5$ ?

Comment: Well, my approach may not suit you. I get lost in algebraic manipulations of this sort, so I would note that exactly one of the following 8 cases must hold for any $x$: $(x \notin A, x \notin B, x \notin C), (x \notin A, x \notin B, x \in C), (x \notin A, x \in B, x \notin C),...$, then show that in each case the left and right side are the same.

Comment: Another observation for 4. (although its not clear how to turn this into a succinct proof) is that $x \in (A \triangle B) \triangle C$ **iff** an odd number of the inclusions $x \in A, x \in B, x \in C$ are true. Then the equality follows immediately.

Comment: @copper.hat You might want to promote your string of comments to an answer?

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Took your suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Looks fine.
2. Use the definition, you know what $A \setminus A$ is.
3. Follows since $C \setminus D = D \setminus C$.
4. Here are two approaches (I get lost in the algebraic manipulations):

(a) Note that exactly one of the following 8 cases must hold for any $x$
(cf. the binary values of 0-7): 
$(x \notin A, x \notin B, x \notin C), (x \notin A, x \notin B, x \in C), (x \notin A, x \in B, x \notin C),...$. 
Then show that in each case, $x$ is in the left set **iff**
$x$ is in the right set.

(b) Note that $1_{(A \triangle B) \triangle C}(x) = 1$ **iff** $x$ is in an odd number of the sets $A,B,C$. Similarly for $1_{A \triangle (B \triangle C)}$.

5. Direct expansion:
   \begin{eqnarray}
   A \cap (B \triangle C) &=& 
   A \cap ((B \cap C^c) \cup (B^c \cap C)) \\
   &=& (A \cap B \cap C^c) \cup (A \cap B^c \cap C) \\
   &=& (A \cap B \cap (C^c \cup A^c)) \cup (A \cap C \cap B^c) \\
   &=& ((A \cap B) \setminus (A \cap C)) \cup (A \cap C \cap (B^c \cup A^c)) \\
   &=& ((A \cap B) \setminus (A \cap C)) \cup ((A \cap C) \setminus (B \cap A)) \\
   &=& (A \cap B) \triangle (A \cap C)
   \end{eqnarray}